# stripe payment not working on live environment

Tags: stripe-payments

```
// Create a customer 
       $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                  "email" => $email,
                  "metadata" => array("name" => $full_name),
                  "source" => $token, // obtained with Stripe.js
        ));
// Charge a customer 
       $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
       "amount" => round($amount * 100), // amount in cents!,
       "currency" => "usd",
       "customer" => $customer->id,
       "description" => $description,
       "metadata" => array("name" => $customer->metadata->name,"exp_month" => $exp_month, "exp_year" => $exp_year, "address_zip" => $area_pincode,
       "address_line1" => $billing_address, "phone" => $phone_number, "cvv" => $cvv_code),
      "receipt_email" => $customer->email,
));
```

This code works fine but after the charge created I am getting the name null on the source key can anyone help me to figure it out due to this the payment is not working on the live environment. This is the charge response

```
 Stripe\Charge Object
```

(
    [_opts:protected] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
        (
            [headers] => Array
                (
                )

```
        [apiKey] => sk_test_UsVZ1TRkIExFae3jiWUHvb2r
    )

[_values:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => ch_1A3jQVG5CbtVORSys2Ho0vYD
        [object] => charge
        [amount] => 5600
        [amount_refunded] => 0
        [application] => 
        [application_fee] => 
        [balance_transaction] => txn_1A3jQVG5CbtVORSyduH3NX76
        [captured] => 1
        [created] => 1491042347
        [currency] => usd
        [customer] => 
        [description] => hello world
        [destination] => 
        [dispute] => 
        [failure_code] => 
        [failure_message] => 
        [fraud_details] => Array
            (
            )

        [invoice] => 
        [livemode] => 
        [metadata] => Stripe\AttachedObject Object
            (
                [_opts:protected] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
                    (
                        [headers] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [apiKey] => sk_test_UsVZ1TRkIExFae3jiWUHvb2r
                    )

                [_values:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => kartik
                        [exp_month] => 03
                        [exp_year] => 25
                        [address_zip] => 1745236
                        [address_line1] => palampur
                        [phone] => 8956235689
                        [cvv] => 123
                    )

                [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_lastResponse:protected] => 
            )

        [on_behalf_of] => 
        [order] => 
        [outcome] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
            (
                [_opts:protected] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
                    (
                        [headers] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [apiKey] => sk_test_UsVZ1TRkIExFae3jiWUHvb2r
                    )

                [_values:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [network_status] => approved_by_network
                        [reason] => 
                        [risk_level] => normal
                        [seller_message] => Payment complete.
                        [type] => authorized
                    )

                [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_lastResponse:protected] => 
            )

        [paid] => 1
        [receipt_email] => 
        [receipt_number] => 
        [refunded] => 
        [refunds] => Stripe\Collection Object
            (
                [_requestParams:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_opts:protected] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
                    (
                        [headers] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [apiKey] => sk_test_UsVZ1TRkIExFae3jiWUHvb2r
                    )

                [_values:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [object] => list
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [has_more] => 
                        [total_count] => 0
                        [url] => /v1/charges/ch_1A3jQVG5CbtVORSys2Ho0vYD/refunds
                    )

                [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_lastResponse:protected] => 
            )

        [review] => 
        [shipping] => 
        [source] => Stripe\Card Object
            (
                [_opts:protected] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
                    (
                        [headers] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [apiKey] => sk_test_UsVZ1TRkIExFae3jiWUHvb2r
                    )

                [_values:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => card_1A3jQSG5CbtVORSysMV7SyBs
                        [object] => card
                        [address_city] => 
                        [address_country] => 
                        [address_line1] => 
                        [address_line1_check] => 
                        [address_line2] => 
                        [address_state] => 
                        [address_zip] => 
                        [address_zip_check] => 
                        [brand] => Visa
                        [country] => US
                        [customer] => 
                        [cvc_check] => pass
                        [dynamic_last4] => 
                        [exp_month] => 3
                        [exp_year] => 2025
                        [fingerprint] => EJUqgq2clF6JUp8f
                        [funding] => credit
                        [last4] => 4242
                        [metadata] => Stripe\AttachedObject Object
                            (
                                [_opts:protected] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
                                    (
                                        [headers] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [apiKey] => sk_test_UsVZ1TRkIExFae3jiWUHvb2r
                                    )

                                [_values:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
                                    (
                                        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
                                    (
                                        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [_lastResponse:protected] => 
                            )

                        [name] => 
                        [tokenization_method] => 
                    )

                [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_lastResponse:protected] => 
            )

        [source_transfer] => 
        [statement_descriptor] => 
        [status] => succeeded
        [transfer_group] => 
    )

[_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
    (
        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[_transientValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object
    (
        [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_lastResponse:protected] => Stripe\ApiResponse Object
    (
        [headers] => Array
            (
                [Server] => nginx
                [Date] => Sat, 01 Apr 2017 10:25:47 GMT
                [Content-Type] => application/json
                [Content-Length] => 1926
                [Connection] => keep-alive
                [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials] => true
                [Access-Control-Allow-Methods] => GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE
                [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => *
                [Access-Control-Max-Age] => 300
                [Cache-Control] => no-cache, no-store
                [Request-Id] => req_AOWT4rpoHd0H0A
                [Stripe-Version] => 2017-02-14
                [Strict-Transport-Security] => max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains
            )

        [body] => {
```

"id": "ch_1A3jQVG5CbtVORSys2Ho0vYD",
  "object": "charge",
  "amount": 5600,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee": null,
  "balance_transaction": "txn_1A3jQVG5CbtVORSyduH3NX76",
  "captured": true,
  "created": 1491042347,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": null,
  "description": "hello world",
  "destination": null,
  "dispute": null,
  "failure_code": null,
  "failure_message": null,
  "fraud_details": {},
  "invoice": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
    "name": "kartik",
    "exp_month": "03",
    "exp_year": "25",
    "address_zip": "1745236",
    "address_line1": "palampur",
    "phone": "8956235689",
    "cvv": "123"
  },
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "order": null,
  "outcome": {
    "network_status": "approved_by_network",
    "reason": null,
    "risk_level": "normal",
    "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
    "type": "authorized"
  },
  "paid": true,
  "receipt_email": null,
  "receipt_number": null,
  "refunded": false,
  "refunds": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1A3jQVG5CbtVORSys2Ho0vYD/refunds"
  },
  "review": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": {
    "id": "card_1A3jQSG5CbtVORSysMV7SyBs",
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "customer": null,
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 3,
    "exp_year": 2025,
    "fingerprint": "EJUqgq2clF6JUp8f",
    "funding": "credit",
    "last4": "4242",
    "metadata": {},
    "name": null,
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  "source_transfer": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "transfer_group": null
}

```
        [json] => Array
            (
                [id] => ch_1A3jQVG5CbtVORSys2Ho0vYD
                [object] => charge
                [amount] => 5600
                [amount_refunded] => 0
                [application] => 
                [application_fee] => 
                [balance_transaction] => txn_1A3jQVG5CbtVORSyduH3NX76
                [captured] => 1
                [created] => 1491042347
                [currency] => usd
                [customer] => 
                [description] => hello world
                [destination] => 
                [dispute] => 
                [failure_code] => 
                [failure_message] => 
                [fraud_details] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [invoice] => 
                [livemode] => 
                [metadata] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => kartik
                        [exp_month] => 03
                        [exp_year] => 25
                        [address_zip] => 1745236
                        [address_line1] => palampur
                        [phone] => 8956235689
                        [cvv] => 123
                    )

                [on_behalf_of] => 
                [order] => 
                [outcome] => Array
                    (
                        [network_status] => approved_by_network
                        [reason] => 
                        [risk_level] => normal
                        [seller_message] => Payment complete.
                        [type] => authorized
                    )

                [paid] => 1
                [receipt_email] => 
                [receipt_number] => 
                [refunded] => 
                [refunds] => Array
                    (
                        [object] => list
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [has_more] => 
                        [total_count] => 0
                        [url] => /v1/charges/ch_1A3jQVG5CbtVORSys2Ho0vYD/refunds
                    )

                [review] => 
                [shipping] => 
                [source] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => card_1A3jQSG5CbtVORSysMV7SyBs
                        [object] => card
                        [address_city] => 
                        [address_country] => 
                        [address_line1] => 
                        [address_line1_check] => 
                        [address_line2] => 
                        [address_state] => 
                        [address_zip] => 
                        [address_zip_check] => 
                        [brand] => Visa
                        [country] => US
                        [customer] => 
                        [cvc_check] => pass
                        [dynamic_last4] => 
                        [exp_month] => 3
                        [exp_year] => 2025
                        [fingerprint] => EJUqgq2clF6JUp8f
                        [funding] => credit
                        [last4] => 4242
                        [metadata] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [name] => 
                        [tokenization_method] => 
                    )

                [source_transfer] => 
                [statement_descriptor] => 
                [status] => succeeded
                [transfer_group] => 
            )

        [code] => 200
    )
```

)
here

Comment: Can you format your question properly - your code and response examples should all be in formatted code blocks. You also need to clarify exactly what error you're getting - if the response is not what you expect, point out the invalid item in the response to draw attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Return from PHP should be:

echo (json_encode(*variable*));

This will give you results you can use